# How can I log into my router with python?

Tags: python, http, http-post, csrf

I am trying to log into my router using python. I'm using the requests library. The login page has two input fields, one for the username, one for the password. Clicking the submit makes a POST request to a different address containing

```js
{"csrf":{"csrf_param":"MP4ePcLs1yYJ64tMVNxrm79V6aN7Vih","csrf_token":"l0AoSk5qsr4kSEMl2lFW9pYad/4DpYJ"},"data":{"UserName":"admin","Password":"[a lot of letters and numbers, not my password]"}}
```

I can see the csrf param and token in the page header, but I'm not sure what I should pass as the password.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cross Site Request Forgery tokens are something different than logon credentials. You have to get it beforehand by a `GET` with the appropriate header. For a more precise answer, you have to provide more detail.

Comment: @BernardMeurer It is a TalkTalk router HG635

Comment: @flaschbier Yes, I understand that, I'm fine with the csrf token. I was wondering how I could get what I need to include for 'Password'

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're really asking.  Why can't you just fill in the "Password" value in that code you posted?

Comment: If the password doesn't change on subsequent requests you can just pass in the numbers each time, otherwise it may be hashing the password or encoding it with base64. It may have a function within the javascript on the page that tokenizes the password. I would check that first.